# how encode php-massive with cyrillic symbols to json?

Tags: javascript, php, json, utf-8

please help find error. i get from mysql several strings. these strings contains cyrillic symbols.

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
  error_reporting(0);
  require('connectDB.php');

  $connect = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
  mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
  mysql_select_db($database);

  $sql = 'SELECT `title` FROM `graphs`';
  $result = mysql_query($sql); // or die(mysql_error());
  $response = array();

  if($result){ 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $response[] = $row["title"];
    };
  }
  else{
    $response = 'error';
  } 

  print_r($response);

  print(json_encode($response)); 
?>
```

but first print operator output follow:

> Array ( [0] => ыва [1] => ввв [2] => ываываывавы )

second print operator output follow:

> ["\u044b\u0432\u0430","\u0432\u0432\u0432","\u044b\u0432\u0430\u044b\u0432\u0430\u044b\u0432\u0430\u0432\u044b"]

i try all files resave with ebcoding utf8 without BOM

Comment: Escapes are fine, but if you want to see letters in your json, try `json_encode(..., JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)` .

Comment: thanks! it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do like below:

```
json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```